# Combining periodic and aperiodic kernels in sklearn GPR

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, bayesian, gaussian-process

I am using the **scikit-learn** Python library to perform Bayesian optimization (on top of Gaussian process regression) on a function which takes seven inputs. Four of these inputs represent physical angles, so the Gaussian kernel should be periodic in them; a natural choice is [`sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.ExpSineSquared`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.ExpSineSquared.html#sklearn-gaussian-process-kernels-expsinesquared). However, I do not want to arbitrarily force the function to be periodic in the other three.

According to [The Kernel Cookbook](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eduvenaud/cookbook/), the proper way to do this is to simply multiply an `ExpSineSquared` kernel over the periodic variables with an aperiodic kernel (say the Matérn kernel) over the others and obtain something like

```
ExpSineSquared(x[:3])*Matern(x[3:])
```

(where `x` is the 7-vector of parameters). One would think that [the `Product` kernel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.Product.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.Product) implemented in `sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels` would be the way to go, but as far as I can tell this would not allow me to choose which parameters are periodic and which are not; using the `Product` kernel would effectively give me `ExpSineSquared(x)*Matern(x)`.

Since I'm not very experienced with GPR in sklearn, what is the best way to implement my desired kernel?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory & methodology.

Comment: @desertnaut I'm asking how to implement a specific form of a kernel to interface with the sklearn library, not what kind of kernel to use. Where else would I ask an implementation question, if not here?